# Different output between Command Line and Code Blocks

Tags: c, shell, command-line

I am trying to implement a library (on linux) to check for more instances of a running program.

The program gets the executable name of the running program, saves it into a binary file ( `.existence` ) together with the programs PID.

Latter, before the program runs (again) does a check to see if there is already an instance of that program by checking if there is the `.existence` file and if so, a comparison is made.

Everything works as expected in `codeblocks` but when I run it in command line the function ( `int find_pid ( const char *const instance )` ) which returns the PID of the program returns `0` instead.

Here is a part of the program which can be compiled and tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void write_bin_file     ( const char *const fileName, const char *const msg );
char *read_bin_File     ( const char *const fileName );
char *my_strtok   ( char *msg );

int find_pid ( const char *const instance );

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    char instance[ strlen( argv[0] ) + 1 ];
    memset( instance, '\0', sizeof( instance ) );

    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        strcpy( instance, argv[0] );

        char *buffer = my_strtok( instance );

        write_bin_file ( ".existence", buffer );

        char *ret = read_bin_File( ".existence" );
        printf( "\n%s\n", ret );

        printf("Actc_pid =\t%d\n", getpid() );
        printf("Find_pid =\t%d\n", find_pid ( buffer ) );
        free( ret );
    }

    sleep( 5 );
}

char *read_bin_File ( const char *const fileName )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( fileName, "rb" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned short len = 0;
    fread( &len, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, fp);

    char *buffer = malloc( sizeof( *buffer ) * len );
    fread( buffer, sizeof( *buffer ), len, fp );

    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}

void write_bin_file( const char *const fileName, const char *const msg )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( fileName, "wb");
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error, write_bin_file()\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
    size_t len = strlen( msg ) + 1;
    fwrite( &len, sizeof( unsigned short ), 1, fp);
    fwrite( msg, sizeof(char), len, fp);
    fclose( fp );
}

int find_pid ( const char *const instance )
{
    char line[256];
    memset( line, '\0', sizeof( *line ) );

    char buffer[555];
    memset( buffer, '\0', sizeof( *buffer ) );

    sprintf( buffer, "ps -A | grep %s", instance );
    FILE *cmd = popen( buffer, "r");

    fgets( line, 256, cmd);
    pid_t pid = (pid_t)strtoul(line, NULL, 10);

    pclose( cmd );
    return pid;
}

char *my_strtok( char *msg )
{
    char *ret = NULL;
    char *tmp = strtok( msg, "/" );
    while ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        ret = tmp;
        tmp = strtok( NULL, "/");
    }

    if ( ret == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Codeblocks Outputs:

```
program
Actc_pid =  11890
Find_pid =  11890
```

Command line Outputs:

```
program
Actc_pid =  11900
Find_pid =  0
```

Valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --track-origins=yes --show-leak-kinds=all Templates/Program/bin/Debug/Program
==12414== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12414== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12414== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12414== Command: Templates/Program/bin/Debug/Program
==12414== 

Program
Actc_pid =  12414
Find_pid =  0
==12414== 
==12414== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12414==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12414==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 14,686 bytes allocated
==12414== 
==12414== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==12414== 
==12414== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==12414== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: the `main()` function could be made a lot simpler by using the function: `basename()` found in the header file: `libgen.h`

Comment: what happens when `argc` is >= 2?

Comment: Why am I asking?  because your question was how to avoid multiple instances of the same program running at the same time and many/most programs take command line parameters

Comment: OT: regarding: `char line[256];
    memset( line, '\0', sizeof( *line ) );`  This would be better written as: `char line[256] = { '\0' };`

Comment: regarding: `fine_pid()`   If there is more than one instance of the program running, it will find the oldest instance of the program

Comment: OT: when calling `fread()` and/or `fwrite()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @user3629249 can you please answer my question? Why is there a different answer?

Comment: so far, no one has posted an answer, only comments.  However, I ran your posted code on my computer (ubuntu linux 18.04)  and it worked correctly

Comment: Run it under valgrind

Comment: the OPs posted code contains some memory leaks.  The OP can easily fix that.  (get rid of the call(s) to `malloc()` and `free()` as neither are needed to perform the desired functionality

Comment: „total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees“ where is the leak?

Comment: here is the output from my running your code: "untitled<newline>
Actc_pid = 29906<newline>
Find_pid = 29906<newline>

Comment: the file: `.existence` contains:  a 4 byte binary value of the pid, followed by the text: `untitled`,  exactly as expected.  Note: my 64bit architecture uses 4 bytes for a 'short int'

Comment: The file does not contain the pid value The file contains the programs name + PID. Eg: program:7815

Comment: Let me explain you the program flow, because we are going in the wrong direction. The program is runned for the first time, saves its information about its name and PID. If you run the program again and the first instance wasn’t exited then the check is made

Comment: If the file exists, if the content of the file is the same with the second instance. If is not, the first one is still running.

Comment: The order of the values written to the file are: `write( &len, sizeof( unsigned short ), 1, fp);`  I.E. the PID then `fwrite( msg, sizeof(char), len, fp);`  I.E. the executable name.  NOT the other way around

Comment: the posted code writes the file, before reading it.  So the contents of the file are always for the current program.

Comment: Yes you right. But in the original there is a read before a write is made

Comment: but you did not give us code that reads first.  We cannot read your mind (at least most of us cannot) so we have to work with what you have posted

Comment: @because I cannot figure out, what has to do with the problem I have. If I remove all and I let only the last printf call will be still the same.